# How to "copy all"?

Tags: 8.0, functionality

Is there a way to quickly **copy all text** in a textbox?
(besides manually mark all words by dragging my finger over them all and then press copy?)

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no built-in way to select all other than manually dragging the selectors.

Comment: Isn't this a basic function that should exist in a mobile OS?